# Infinite separable extensions

Tags: galois-theory, fields

Let $L/K$ be an infinite algebraic separable extension of fields. One assumes that the fields are embedded in an algebraic closure $\Omega$. Consider an element $\alpha$ of $\Omega$ separable over $L$. Is $K(a)$ a separable extension of $K$?

When $L/K$ is a finite extension, it is pretty easy to prove. But what about in the infinite dimensional case?

Comment: yes, I forgot the word separable. I edited the question.

Comment: Towers of (finite) separable extensions are separable, this follows from $B/A$ is finite separable iff $[B:A]=|Hom_A(B,\overline{B})|$. Here the tower of finite separable extensions is $F(a)/F/K$ where $F$ is $K$ plus the coefficients of $a$'s $L$-minimal polynomial.